# VB.Net Extension Function Not a Member of String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, extension-methods

I am attempting to fold in some common functionality throughout our asp.net app into some string extension methods but I am running into an issue where our site is kicking out compiler errors that the methods are not members of String.

Here is the module definition in the Utilities namespace I created:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Namespace Utilities    
    'This extension extends the String class with new functions to check string validity.  Add any such new functions here
    <Extension()> _
    Public Module StringExtensions
        <Extension()> _
        Public Function IsAlphaNumeric(targ As String) As Boolean
            Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(targ, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
        End Function

        Public Function IsNumeric(targ As String) As Boolean
            Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(targ, "^[0-9]+$")
        End Function

        Public Function RegexRemove(targ As String, rpl As String) As String
            Return Regex.Replace(targ, rpl, "")
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Here is the location I am attempting to call the extension methods from along with a example of a call to one of them:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports Utilities
Imports Utilities.StringExtensions
Imports Utilities.PageOps
Imports Utilities.DBChecks

Public Class UserDashboard
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    '...

    Private Function GetRoleLst(rMap As Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)) As List(Of String)
        Dim rLst As New List(Of String)()

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In rMap
            For Each con As Control In ThRolePanel.Controls
                If TypeOf con Is CheckBox Then
                    Dim conID As String = con.ID
                    If DirectCast(con, CheckBox).Checked And conID.RegexRemove("\s") = kvp.Key Then
                        rLst.Add(kvp.Value)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Our Web.config file is pointing at .net 4.0 and System.Core has been added to the assemblies list.  Here is the compilation tab:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
         <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.2.14.1204, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
        <add assembly="Telerik.Reporting.Service, Version=8.2.14.1204, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
        <add assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.2.14.1204, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
      </assemblies>

      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
```

Have looked through a number of SO questions, guides on VB extension functions, and .net documentation but none of it has helped me figure this out so far.

---

Update

So off a hunch I tried accessing the extension methods by going in through the namespace like this:

> Utilities.RegexReplace(con.ID,"\s")

and that worked but if I try to access it as an extension of String I am still getting the previous issue where it reports the "RegexReplace" is not a member of string error.  It seems like the extension method is not actually extending String for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure that the extension methods themselves are compiling. I noticed that you are fully qualifying `Regex` in all but the `RegexRemove` method and you have no include for the `System.Text` namespace, so I am thinking that code itself is not compiling. Can you post your compiler errors?

Comment: @pstrjds This is a code behind for an asp.net website.  The site compiles itself at runtime and then outputs errors if there are any.  The error I am seeing is "RegexReplace" is not a member of String.  This also happens for the other two methods as well.

This is a very old application and the previous developer deleted the project and solution files when he left so I can't compile it in Vis Studio.  I found something interesting, check my question for the update.

Comment: You have added the `Extension` attribute to `IsAlphaNumeric` but not to `IsNumeric` or `RegexRemove`.

Comment: @Geowil - Did you mean `RegexRemove`, because `RegexReplace` is not a member of that extension class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney doh!  Been staring at code for too long today apparently.  That fixed it.  Create an answer with that and I will accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: @pstrjds yes, that was what I meant.  jmcilhinney was correct, I needed to add the extension keyword to each method.  The time that IsAlphaNumeric did not work was due to not including the extension module properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the `Extension` attribute to `IsAlphaNumeric` but not to `IsNumeric` or `RegexRemove`.  This:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function IsAlphaNumeric(targ As String) As Boolean
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(targ, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
End Function

Public Function IsNumeric(targ As String) As Boolean
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(targ, "^[0-9]+$")
End Function

Public Function RegexRemove(targ As String, rpl As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(targ, rpl, "")
End Function
```

should be this:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function IsAlphaNumeric(targ As String) As Boolean
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(targ, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
End Function

<Extension()> _
Public Function IsNumeric(targ As String) As Boolean
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(targ, "^[0-9]+$")
End Function

<Extension()> _
Public Function RegexRemove(targ As String, rpl As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(targ, rpl, "")
End Function
```

Comment: Also `<Extension()>` attribute is not required to the `Module` itself.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, but it can be applied legally, so I'm wondering if there is any value to doing so. On a type, it is supposed to indicate that that type contains extension methods so I suspect that, if you apply it to a member, the compiler will automatically apply it to the type. That would mean that doing so yourself would have no value and I can't say I've ever noticed a detriment to not doing so.